# '[Errno 13] Permission denied' from open() in python, when the file SHOULD be accessible

Tags: python, windows

I've seen an error in one of our CI scripts where trying to `open` a file in a python script fails with the error `[Errno 13] Permission denied` (this is on a windows machine)

I'm wondering how it's possible, given what's going on:

First, we start a process in the background, which is responsible for generating this file. It does so by first creating a temporary file, writing the needed data to it, and then renaming it to the final name (i.e. the one we get the permissions error while attempting to open). To rename the file, the background process calls `_wrename`

The python script, after starting this process, waits for the file to be generated via calling `os.path.exists` on the path, until it returns true.

After it's learned that the file exists, it tries to open the file (simply using `open(path)`), and we get the permissions error.

I don't see what could possibly be changing the permissions on this file after it's been created.

The only idea I have is that when the python script is trying to open the file, the rename is still in progress somehow, and so the permissions issue is caused by a 'sharing violation', which it seems can present as a permissions issue?

But I was under the impression that renaming a file should be atomic? This is happening on a local drive (file stays in the same folder, just the name changes).

Unfortunately I've only seen this error once, and don't have any way to reproduce it.

Comment: `don't have any way to reproduce it.` - add extra logging for the next time it happens.  When it happens, after logging then maybe add code to try a sleep in case the other process still has a lock on the file then retry, and log the result of that (success or failure).

Comment: have you tried to `ls -lsah` in the directory that has the file? Maybe you need to `chown` the file or `chmod` the permissions?

Comment: @duhaime This is windows. Also, we're running both the background process & the python process as the same user, so if it's able to create the file, it should be able to open it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run python file with sudo:

```
sudo python3 python_script.py
```

Or in Windows run console/IDE as administrator.

Comment: Given that the background process & python are running as the same user, that shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: I just remember I've had similar issue and only running script/pyCharm with sudo helped to solve it.. Is it possible that you're trying to open file while it's opened in another process?

Comment: strictly speaking, read permissions and write permissions may not align ... but usually, true if you can write you can read...

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to write and read simultaneously..

Comment: There _shouldn't_ be anything else opening that file, it's just been created, and there's no reason for anyone else to use it (maybe some anti-virus, but they should be smart enough to open the file w/ sharing permitted?)